# How to Hover/Overlay Image in Listview as seen in this Demo

Tags: android, listview

I'm very newbie to Android. I am trying to make listview from XML, and want to create layout as shown in demo pic, round icon needs to overlay and boder should remain below title (manager). Green bar as border color on top only (optional)

Demo Pic :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a seek bar with 2 images one as foreground and another one is background   this is for the top logo
this goes into the layout

```
        <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:thumb="@null"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar" />
```

seek_bar.xml   goes into the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/greyed_logo"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/colored_logo"/>

</layer-list>
```

your list item should be an image above a progress bar , also customized
and a textview
an image above a progress bar can be achieved using FrameLayout or RelativeLayout

this is the xml for the rest of the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:thumb="@null"
            android:progress="70" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is some text that should be in a text view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is what it would look like

you change how much blue line you want to see by setting its progress, in range of 0-100, programmatically in your code
[image]

**EDIT ** with title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="70"
            android:thumb="@null" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="this is the title"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is some text that should be in a text view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

image result:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, What about the textview (Manager) right beside Image (icon)

Comment: you need xml for that ?

Comment: the xml i gave you , is for the big logo

Comment: Great reply. Thank You. Thumbs up to ur answer

Comment: Can u add title (Manager) textview in ur answer . it will make a complete answer